# How to write to a JSON file in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently requiring a JSON file which I am reading data from.

```
var allUORHours = require('./UORHoursAch.json');
```

How do I then write to the file? The below doesn't make any changes to the file

```
allUORHours.test = {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the File System API's writeFile():

> https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

No, of course it doesn't. It just changes the variable's value. To write a JSON, you would need to convert to JSON, then write to a file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('./UORHoursAch.json', JSON.stringify(allUORHours), function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Saved");
  }
});
```